# Appium Javascript ( WD Promise) function to check if android keyboard is on

Tags: javascript, android, appium, appium-android

Do we have a function to find if android keyboard is on in Appium javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to a direct function to check the status of keyboard but i have used the below approach

```
        try {
            this.driver.hideKeyboard();
            element.click(); // to open the keyboard
        }catch(err) {
            element.click(); // to open the keyboard
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `driver.isKeyboardShown`

Comment: This seems to be more like a comment but not an answer. Please see Stack Overflow help [How to answer section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)